# Get generated SQL String from sequel Database

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there a way to get the `CREATE TABLE …` SQL string generated by the following Seqel statement? I have looked at the source but found nothing.

```
DB.create_table :organisations do
  primary_key :id
  String :external_id, size: 255
  String :external_source, size: 255
  String :name, size: 255
  DateTime :created_at
  DateTime :updated_at
  DateTime :deleted_at
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple ways to see what's being generated.

- Use the `-E` flag if you're using the Sequel console to process migrations.
- In code you can define a Logger instance and tell Sequel to use it:

  ```
  require 'sequel'
  require 'logger'

  DB = Sequel.connect('some DSN')
  DB.loggers << Logger.new(STDOUT)
  ```

  Run your code and you'll see the SQL being generated as Sequel runs. You can do this instead of using `-E` in the console if you choose.

If you take this code, and save it to a file and run it:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.loggers << Logger.new(STDOUT)

DB.create_table :organisations do
  primary_key :id
  String :external_id, size: 255
  String :external_source, size: 255
  String :name, size: 255
  DateTime :created_at
  DateTime :updated_at
  DateTime :deleted_at
end
```

You'll get:

```
I, [2014-09-12T14:14:49.509469 #75341]  INFO -- : (0.000111s) PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1
I, [2014-09-12T14:14:49.509560 #75341]  INFO -- : (0.000025s) PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = 1
I, [2014-09-12T14:14:49.509870 #75341]  INFO -- : (0.000244s) CREATE TABLE `organisations` (`id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `external_id` varchar(255), `external_source` varchar(255), `name` varchar(255), `created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp, `deleted_at` timestamp)
```

If you want that output to go to a file you can use a file handle instead of STDOUT:

```
DB.loggers << Logger.new('sql_logger.log')
```

See [the Logger documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-How+to+create+a+logger) for more information.

You can even capture that into a String using [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/index.html) or by temporarily assigning where STDOUT or STDERR go.